# Canonical question on Indian passport damage

Tags: discussion, canonical-questions

We have a plethora of questions on this site asking for advice about damaged Indian passport. The damage comes in wide varities - threading coming off, torn pages, water/other smears or detached cover. [A Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Atravel.stackexchange.com+indian+passport+damaged) points to a lot of such questions.

Most of these questions have a picture of passport which makes them more of an opinion poll on degree of damage.

The common answer to all these is to point to official page which quantifies damage and the procedure to get a new one.

- Should we create a new canonical question for this and close *all* existing ones as duplicate?
- Or pick the oldest/ most generic one and mark all others as duplicate of that?
- Or just continue closing all new questions as duplicate(of whichever similar one we find at that time)/opinion based?

Answer (score 5):

Yes let's create a canonical and start closing questions about damaged passports. Nipping this in the bud is the best way to go about it IMHO.

Comment: Maybe make it community wiki so it can be expanded easily?

Comment: @JJJ By all means yes.

Comment: I found [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/60179/50234)  that is very close to generic (has been heavily edited to get there).