# Should we add a indian-passport-damage tag?

Tags: discussion

We should consider adding a **indian-passport-damage** tag, since questions about this topic regularly occur.

Mainly:

- smeared official stamp on cover page (with photo)

This may make it easier to find similar questions that already have an answer.

Latest sample: [visas - Passport cover page - Travel Stack Exchange](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/176786/passport-cover-page)
[image]

---

See also: [2019-05-11: Canonical question on Indian passport damage - Travel Meta Stack Exchange](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5099/canonical-question-on-indian-passport-damage)

Comment: Why restrict it to Indian passports?

Comment: @Willeke Mainly because this is a reoccuring problen (smeared official stamp on cover page) on indian passports. In the last months a few dozen times (I would guess). Many modern passports no longer use rubber stamps and this problem seems to exist when they are first issued. It is also not a normal wear and tear of existing passports.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have made the tag damaged passports, (without the restriction Indian as I feel every passport has the risk of becoming damaged) and will add it to those questions I see about them. (But I am not going back through all older questions to apply it.)

It will be good to have it added to those questions we use for duplicates, either damaged or not really damaged.

Comment: Would it be to late to change this to **passport-damaged**, so when typing in *passport* the user can see and select it?

Comment: Sorry, I would not know that. Maybe a good reason to wait with adding it to more questions for now.

Comment: Yes, I stopped doing so after I saw that many already had the **passport** tag.

Comment: We could add a tag synonym for `passport-damaged`, yes? Leaving this one as the primary.